# unable to pass a parameter to dir command from perl script

Tags: perl, cmd, directory

I am unable to execute the `dir` command, i get error when specifying the file name `all.xml` to search and i can't make the search recursive using the `/s` command , i get the following error `cannot access no such file exists` and it is not understanding that `/s` parameter is for searching recursively ,program interprets it as a file path

```
use strict;
use warnings;  
print "i";
my $vall = ` dir  //server1/dxx/mxx/rxx/ "ui.xml"  /s`; 

print $vall;
```

Comment: Is this on windows? You will probably need backslashes.

Comment: @simbabque   yes windows,i can't write backlashes , the cygwin tool in the cmd  asks me to write the posix equivalent when i execute the command, i am able to list all the files in `rxx` folder using forward slashes  but i can't recursively find files because `/s` parameter is interpreted as a file path

Comment: Put the switch before the path.

Comment: @simbabque tried that as well it doesn't work if  do this `dir  //server1/dxx/mxx/rss/ ` , it displays all the files present in 'rss' but when i write the `file name ` and `/s` , i get the error `no such file or directory` it also includes file name `ui.xml`  in the path

Comment: Try `-s` instead. Sounds weird, but as I remember, Unix like paths also means Unix like options.

Comment: @PerlDuck no i tried that too it didn't work it just displayed contents  in `rss` folder

Comment: My Windows and cygwin expertise is a bit rusty. But what does `dir  //server1/dxx/mxx/rxx/ "ui.xml"` mean? Do you want to list `//server1/dxx/mxx/rxx/` **and** `ui.xml`? Like calling `dir` with two parameters, a directory and a file?

Comment: @PerlDuck, Re "*Unix like paths also means Unix like options*", That's complete nonsense.

Comment: @PerlDuck no `ui.xml ` is a file name

Comment: Re "*no ui.xml is a file name*", Then it needs to be connected to the path. `dir /s/b c:\a.jpg` will search for `a.jpg` everywhere on your `C:`.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Perl. The arguments you are passing to `dir` are incorrect.

- `dir` interprets `/` as the start of an option unless it's quoted,
- you have a space in the middle of the path that shouldn't be there, and
- `/s` doesn't work with paths containing both `/` and a file component.

Additionally, you probably want `/b` in addition to `/s`.

Fixed:

```
dir "\\server1\dxx\mxx\rxx\ui.xml" /s/b
```

so

```
my $dir_output = `dir "\\\\server1\\dxx\\mxx\\rxx\\ui.xml" /s/b`;
```

Example,

```
>dir "//localhost/C$/Users/ikegami/Desktop/" /s/b
\\localhost\C$\Users\ikegami\Desktop\a.jpg
\\localhost\C$\Users\ikegami\Desktop\cabinet.txt
...

>dir "//localhost/C$/Users/ikegami/Desktop/a.jpg" /s/b
File Not Found                                               <-- WTF?

>dir "\\localhost\C$\Users\ikegami\Desktop\a.jpg" /s/b
\\localhost\C$\Users\ikegami\Desktop\a.jpg
\\localhost\C$\Users\ikegami\Desktop\x\a.jpg

>dir \\localhost\C$\Users\ikegami\Desktop\a.jpg /s/b
\\localhost\C$\Users\ikegami\Desktop\a.jpg
\\localhost\C$\Users\ikegami\Desktop\x\a.jpg

>type a.pl
print `dir \\\\localhost\\C\$\\Users\\ikegami\\Desktop\\a.jpg /s/b`

>perl a.pl
\\localhost\C$\Users\ikegami\Desktop\a.jpg
\\localhost\C$\Users\ikegami\Desktop\x\a.jpg
```

---

That said, I'd personally use [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule).

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

my $qfns =
   File::Find::Rule
   ->name('ui.xml')
   ->file
   ->in('//server1/dxx/mxx/rxx');
```

Comment: no `/s` is still interpreted as path `/s:no such file or directory ` , and `ui.xml` is a file which i am trying it search inside `rss` and its sub directories

Comment: i tried the command , and this is the error i got `cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: \server1\dxx\mxx\rxx\ui.xml
l
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/d/server1/dxx/mxx/rxx/ui.xml
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
dir: cannot access \\\\server1\\dxx\\mxx\\rxx\\ui.xml: N
o such file or directory
dir: cannot access /s: No such file or directory
dir: cannot access /b: No such file or directory`

Comment: but when i try this ` `dir   "//server1/dxx/mxx/rxx/"  /s ` i get all the directories under `rxx` and also `cannot access /s :no such directory` , `/s' switch is still interpreted as path

Comment: You're in a Unix emulation environment, passing a `cmd` command to `sh` (where `dir` appears to be an alias for `ls` (which means you have an poorly configured shell)). If you want to execute a `cmd` command, you will need to execute `cmd`.

Comment: i wrote  `cmd`  on the command line and then executed the program still doesn't work

Comment: and i am also in a windows server , i am confused

Comment: now i can do this as well `system("ls  //server1/dxx/mxx/rxx/")` , it lists all the files , can i search for file name  and do recursive search with this command

Comment: i have also tried `File::Find::Rule` before  it takes forever  to get the output , so i am looking for an alternative , i found `psexec` commands handy  for instance `psexec \\server1 cmd` will give the cmd of the  required server and from there i can execute the `dir` command but i am unable to incorporate it in the script , when i execute ` qx(psexec \\server1  cmd)` the cmd hangs there , is there any other alternative , i can use `psexec` in the script

Comment: one last thing ,when i execute the `dir` command in the cmd i get no error and i get the desired output  am not asked to follow unix environment rules ,why is that